# Implementing a countdown timer in React with Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Im trying to render a count down timer on screen with react hooks, but I'm not sure the best way to render it.

I know i'm supposed to use the useEffect to compare current state to previous state, but I don't think I'm doing it correctly.

I would appreciate the help!

I've tried a couple of different ways, none of them work, like setting state whenever whenever it updates, but it just ends up flickering like crazy.

````
const Timer = ({ seconds }) => {
    const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = useState('');

    const now = Date.now();
    const then = now + seconds * 1000;

    const countDown = setInterval(() => {
        const secondsLeft = Math.round((then - Date.now()) / 1000);
        if(secondsLeft <= 0) {
            clearInterval(countDown);
            console.log('done!');
            return;
        }
        displayTimeLeft(secondsLeft);
    }, 1000);

    const displayTimeLeft = seconds => {
        let minutesLeft = Math.floor(seconds/60) ;
        let secondsLeft = seconds % 60;
        minutesLeft = minutesLeft.toString().length === 1 ? "0" + minutesLeft : minutesLeft;
        secondsLeft = secondsLeft.toString().length === 1 ? "0" + secondsLeft : secondsLeft;
        return `${minutesLeft}:${secondsLeft}`;
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setInterval(() => {
            setTimeLeft(displayTimeLeft(seconds));
        }, 1000);
    }, [seconds])


    return (
        <div><h1>{timeLeft}</h1></div>
    )
}

export default Timer;```
````

Comment: Classic issue with hooks and intervals. Have  look at https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/

Comment: And pay attention to canceling the interval also on teardown

Answer (score 80):

```
const Timer = ({ seconds }) => {
  // initialize timeLeft with the seconds prop
  const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = useState(seconds);

  useEffect(() => {
    // exit early when we reach 0
    if (!timeLeft) return;

    // save intervalId to clear the interval when the
    // component re-renders
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      setTimeLeft(timeLeft - 1);
    }, 1000);

    // clear interval on re-render to avoid memory leaks
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
    // add timeLeft as a dependency to re-rerun the effect
    // when we update it
  }, [timeLeft]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{timeLeft}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Does it make more sense to use setTimer here?

Comment: @AmirShitrit Do you mean `setTimeout`? Both are valid options but `setTimeout` suppose to trigger the function once while `setInterval` suppose to trigger the function every x amount of time. because of the nature of `useEffect` where we need to set and clear the timer every time `timeLeft` changes i guess it doesn't really act like a "real" `setInterval` and i can see your point of `setTimeout` in this case.

Comment: Yes. I meant set Timeout. Thanks!

Comment: @AmirShitrit Yes, I prefer setTimeout

Comment: the thing i like most about this is that it works.

Comment: Could be made more robust against setInterval drift by calculating a `Date.now() - start` delta instead of subtracting one second at a time.

Comment: isn't it setting interval over and over.

Answer (score 13):

You should use `setInterval`. I just wanted to add a slight improvement over @Asaf solution. *You do not have to reset the interval every time you change the value.* It's gonna remove the interval and add a new one every time (Might as well use a `setTimeout` in that case). So you can remove the dependencies of your `useEffect` (i.e. `[]`):

```
function Countdown({ seconds }) {
  const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = useState(seconds);

  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      setTimeLeft((t) => t - 1);
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, []);

  return <div>{timeLeft}s</div>;
}
```

Working example:

[image: Countdown example]

Note in the setter, we need to use this syntax `(t) => t - 1` so that we get the latest value each time (see: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates).

---

**Edit (22/10/2021)**

If you want to use a `setInterval` and stop the counter at 0, here is what you can do:

```
function Countdown({ seconds }) {
  const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = useState(seconds);
  const intervalRef = useRef(); // Add a ref to store the interval id

  useEffect(() => {
    intervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      setTimeLeft((t) => t - 1);
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
  }, []);

  // Add a listener to `timeLeft`
  useEffect(() => {
    if (timeLeft <= 0) {
      clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
    }
  }, [timeLeft]);

  return <div>{timeLeft}s</div>;
}
```

[image: Countdown example]

Comment: The interval will run infinitely

Comment: You could stop the counter by unmounting the component if you want to stop at 0: `{seconds > 0 && <Countdown seconds={seconds} />}`. But true, depending on the requirements, it might need some adjustments. Here it won't update the interval value if you update the `seconds` in props either. I just wanted to present a valid alternative to `setTimeout`, using `setInterval` (and not resetting it each render).

Comment: That's the thing, the parent doesn't know anything about `timeLeft`, updating the interval on each re-render is perfectly fine and gives you options to do things when `timeLeft` reaches a certain point like 0. You could do it inside the state updater callback but that's just ugly in my opinion

Comment: ESLint has a rule `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` that enforces adding the dependency of `timeLeft` in the array. But still, agree with not having to clear the interval every time. I think in that case I'll have to use `setTimeout`

Comment: Will this actually be exact? Isn't there some tiny amount time passing between the next execution of `useEffect`?

Answer (score 5):

Here's another alternative with setTimeout

```
const useCountDown = (start) => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(start);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (counter === 0) {
      return;
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
      setCounter(counter - 1);
    }, 1000);
  }, [counter]);
  return counter;
};
```

Example

[image: Edit fragrant-currying-512ky]

Answer (score 1):

Here's my version of a hook, with a "stop" countdown.
Also, I added a "fps" (frames p/sec), to show the countdown with decimal places!

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'

interface ITimer {
    timer: number
    startTimer: (time: number) => void
    stopTimer: () => void
}

interface IProps {
    start?: number
    fps?: number
}

const useCountDown = ({ start, fps }: IProps): ITimer => {
    const [timer, setTimer] = useState(start || 0)
    const intervalRef = useRef<NodeJS.Timer>()

    const stopTimer = () => {
        if (intervalRef.current) clearInterval(intervalRef.current)
    }

    const startTimer = (time: number) => {
        setTimer(time)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (timer <= 0) return stopTimer()
        intervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
            setTimer((t) => t - 1 / (fps || 1))
        }, 1000 / (fps || 1))
        return () => {
            if (intervalRef.current) clearInterval(intervalRef.current)
        }
    }, [timer])

    return { timer, startTimer, stopTimer }
}

export default useCountDown
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small component - `CountdownTimer` - accepting an input parameter `expiresIn` representing the time left in seconds.

We use useState to define `min` and `sec` which we display on the screen, and also we use `timeLeft` to keep track of the time that's left.

We use useEffect to decrement `timeLeft` and recalculate `min` and `sec` every second.

Also, we use formatTime to format the minutes and seconds before displaying them on the screen. If minutes and seconds are both equal to zero we stop the countdown timer.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';


const CountdownTimer = ({expiresIn}) => {
    const [min, setMin] = useState(0);
    const [sec, setSec] = useState(0);
    const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = useState(expiresIn);

    const formatTime = (t) => t < 10 ? '0' + t : t;

    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            const m = Math.floor(timeLeft / 60);
            const s = timeLeft - m * 60;

            setMin(m);
            setSec(s);
            if (m <= 0 && s <= 0) return () => clearInterval(interval);

            setTimeLeft((t) => t - 1);
          }, 1000);

          return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, [timeLeft]);

    return (
        <>
            <span>{formatTime(min)}</span> : <span>{formatTime(sec)}</span>
        </>
    );
}

export default CountdownTimer;
```

Optionally we can pass a setter `setIsTerminated` to trigger an event in the parent component once the countdown is completed.

```
const CountdownTimer = ({expiresIn, setIsTerminated = null}) => {
    ...
```

For example, we can trigger it when minutes and seconds are both equal to zero:

```
if (m <= 0 && s <= 0) {
    if (setTerminated) setIsTerminated(true);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
}
```