# React native timer with hooks

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I'm trying to make a timer with hooks but when I start the app, it's still counting only secs down, even if secs below 0. I couldn't find where the problem is

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'

export default App = () => {

  const [mins, setMins] = useState(2)
  const [secs, setSecs] = useState(2)

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      if (secs <= 0) {
        if (mins <= 0) alert('end')
        else {
          setMins(m => m - 1)
          setSecs(59)
        }
      }
      else setSecs(s => s - 1)
    }, 1000)
  }, [])

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>

      <Text style={{ fontSize: 40 }}>
        {mins}:{secs < 10 && 0}{secs}
      </Text>

    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: you should be aware of the use of setInterval and react re-renders , as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57137094/implementing-a-countdown-timer-in-react-with-hooks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

Don't forget to return from `useEffect` and clearInterval.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'

export default App = () => {

  const [mins, setMins] = useState(2)
  const [secs, setSecs] = useState(2)

  useEffect(() => {
    const timerId = setInterval(() => {
      if (secs <= 0) {
        if (mins <= 0) alert('end')
        else {
          setMins(m => m - 1)
          setSecs(59)
        }
      }
      else setSecs(s => s - 1)
    }, 1000)
    return () => clearInterval(timerId);
  }, [secs, mins])

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>

      <Text style={{ fontSize: 40 }}>
        {mins}:{secs < 10 && 0}{secs}
      </Text>

    </View>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the `React.useState`, like the `this.setState`, it is an async function, you should not call them at the same time.
Secondly,`React.useEffect` like the `componentDidMount`,`componentDidUpdate`,`componentWillMount`. you have to return when the your condition is not match and clearInterval.
my solution code is the following:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'

export default App = () => {

  const [time, setTime] = useState({mins:2,secs:2})


  useEffect(() => {
    if(time.mins<0){ if(timerId) {clearInterval(timerId)} return}
    const timerId = setInterval(() => {
      if (time.secs <= 0) {
        if (time.mins <= 0) {
        setTime({...time,mins:time.mins-1,secs:time.secs}) 
        alert('end')
        }
      else {
          setTime({...time,mins:time.mins-1,secs:59})
        }
      }
      else setTime({...time,mins:time.mins,secs:time.secs-1})
    }, 1000)
    return () => clearInterval(timerId);
  }, [time])

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>

      <Text style={{ fontSize: 40 }}>
        {time.mins>=0 ? time.mins : 0}:{time.secs < 10 && 0}{time.secs}
      </Text>

    </View>
  )
}
```

But for the react-native suggest way, the `setState` should use in the component,
the pure component should not `React.useState`, if you need it, you could use React. Component