# clearInterval not working if using setState React.js

Tags: reactjs, use-state, clearinterval

I'm building a countdown timer with React and encountered this: clearInterval works onCklick if it doesn't update the component. If I update state within the interval function clearInterval doesn't clear the interval anymore. I understand that it has to do with the component re-rendering? Here is the relevant part of the code. Advice is much appreciated:

```
const [sessionCount, setSessionCount] = useState(25);
const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = useState("25:00")

  
var timer ;
 
function startHandle() {
    let endTime = (sessionCount * 60000) + +new Date();
    timer = setInterval(function() {
        let diff = endTime - +new Date();
        const min = Math.floor(diff / 60000);
        const sec = Math.floor((diff / 1000) % 60);
        setTimeLeft(min + ":" + sec) //if this line is removed, then clearInterval works
    }, 1000)
};
```

```
function resetHandle() {
  setTimeLeft("25:00");
  clearInterval(timer);
};
```

```
<div id="time-display-container">
    <div id="timer-label">Session</div>
    <time id="time-left"></time>
    <button id="start_stop" onClick={startHandle}>start/stop</button>
    <button id="reset" onClick={resetHandle}>reset</button>
</div>
```

Comment: On re-render,`timer` is not retaining its last value.  Better Save it in a `ref` using `useRef` to persist its values between re-renders.

Comment: Possible duplicated of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57137094/implementing-a-countdown-timer-in-react-with-hooks

Comment: @Giovanni Esposito thanks, it seems I was bad at going through at already asked questions. I'll try to fix this with both ref and useEffect to get better at react.

Comment: @Rohit Khanna thanks, I'll try both useRef and useEffect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the timer outside the App component.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

let timer;


export default function App() {
  const [sessionCount, setSessionCount] = useState(25);
  const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = useState("25:00");


  function startHandle() {
    let endTime = sessionCount * 60000 + +new Date();
    timer = setInterval(function () {
      let diff = endTime - +new Date();
      const min = Math.floor(diff / 60000);
      const sec = Math.floor((diff / 1000) % 60);
      setTimeLeft(min + ":" + sec); //if this line is removed, then clearInterval works
    }, 1000);
  }

  function resetHandle() {
    setTimeLeft("25:00");
    clearInterval(timer);
  }

  return (
    <div id="time-display-container">
      <div id="timer-label">Session</div>
      <time id="time-left" />
      {timeLeft}
      <button id="start_stop" onClick={startHandle}>
        start/stop
      </button>
      <button id="reset" onClick={resetHandle}>
        reset
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

also, you check for the timer value to prevent multiple set intervals to be set.
I guess defining this timer in useEffect and calling them in some other state change would be more reactive, but the above code is a fix that worked for me in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-panini-f5ibt?file=/src/App.js)