Problem in receiving notification in React-native
i have a problem in react native expo push notifications
the main goal of my app is that fetchs data from a google sheet file and display it
in this code the i have fetch method that checks every 20 seconds if new items added update the data
  const fetchData = async () => {
    setIsFetching(true); 
    try {
      const data = await FetchData();
      setValue(data);

      const newLength = data.length; 
      let hasNewItems = false; 

      if (data && newLength > prevLengthRef.current) {
        console.log("New Order Received:",newLength - prevLengthRef.current,"new items added");
        await sendNotification(expoPushToken);
        hasNewItems = true; // Set flag if new items found
        setInitialLength(newLength);
        prevLengthRef.current = newLength;
      } else {
        console.log("No new orders received.");
      }
      // }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error:", error.message);
    } 

in this code it execute the function every 20seconds
  fetchData(); // Initial fetch

  const intervalId = setInterval(fetchData, 20000); // Fetch data every 20 seconds

  return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
}, []); 

this is function for sending notification
  const sendNotification = async () => {
    try {
      console.log("Sending push notification...");
      // notification message
      const message = {
        to: expoPushToken,
        sound: "default",
        title: "New Order ",
        body: "Open the app new order received ",
      };

      await fetch("https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          host: "exp.host",
          accept: "application/json",
          "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
          "content-type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(message),
      });
      console.log("Notification sent successfully!");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error sending notification:", error);
      Alert.alert("Error", "Failed to send notification");
    }
  };


and it works when i put the function in a Button
<Button title="Send push notification" onPress={sendNotification} />


Hello can you please write proper question ?

An empty dependency array means that the effect does not depend on any values from the component scope. Therefore, it should only run once after the initial render and not on any subsequent renders.

how can i solve this ?

I would leave the fectData() function in your actual useEffect. Then I would create a variable using useState to count the seconds. Today you are using 20 seconds but perhaps in future you will change it, so use a CONST for that interval. This link will give you a good reference to implement the counter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57137094/implementing-a-countdown-timer-in-react-with-hooks
